# Adding a new string to the end of a specific line in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python hence I am unable to implement the solutions I've found online in order to fix my problem.
I am trying to add a specific string to the end of a specific line to a textfile. As I understand text commands, I must overwrite the file if I don't want to append to the end of it. So, my solution is as follows:

```
    ans = 'test'
numdef = ['H',2] 
f = open(textfile, 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open(textfile, 'w')
f.write('')
f.close()
f = open(textfile, 'a')
for line in lines:
    if int(line[0]) == numdef[1]:
        if str(line[2]) == numdef[0]:
                k = ans+ line
                f.write(k)
    else:
        f.write(line)
```

Basically, I am trying to add variable `ans` to the end of a specific line, the line which appears in my list `numdef`. So, for example, for

> 2 H: 4,0 : Where to search for information : google

I want

> 2 H: 4,0 : Where to search for information : google test

I have also tried using `line.insert()` but to no avail.

I understand using the 'a' function of the open command is not so relevant and helpful here, but I am out of ideas. Would love tips with this code, or if maybe I should scrap it and rethink the whole thing.
Thank you for your time and advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You don't have an else case if it meets the first requirement but not the other.

```
ans = 'test'
numdef = ['H',2] 
f = open(textfile, 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open(textfile, 'w')
f.write('')
f.close()
f = open(textfile, 'a')
for line in lines:
    if int(line[0]) == numdef[1] and str(line[2]) == numdef[0]:
        k = line.replace('\n','')+ans
        f.write(k)
    else:
        f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Better way:

```
#initialize variables
ans = 'test' 
numdef = ['H',2]  
#open file in read mode, add lines into lines
with open(textfile, 'r') as f:
    lines=f.readlines() 
#open file in write mode, override everything    
with open(textfile, 'w') as f: 
    #in the list comprehension, loop through each line in lines, if both of the conditions are true, then take the line, remove all newlines, and add ans. Otherwise, remove all the newlines and don't add anything. Then combine the list into a string with newlines as separators ('\n'.join), and write this string to the file.
    f.write('\n'.join([line.replace('\n','')+ans if int(line[0]) == numdef[1] and str(line[2]) == numdef[0] else line.replace('\n','') for line in lines]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The first stack of code gives me the same problem more or less - It writes 'test' in the beginning of the next line. The second does the same and creates spaces between lines, which will cause issues for me if I try to run the function again

Comment: Oops... forgot to remove newlines. Does the second work now?

Comment: It works! Thank you! Could you give me a short run-down of the code so I can understand it completely?

Comment: Sure, I'll add that

Comment: Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

When you use the method

```
lines = f.readlines()
```

Python automatically adds "\n" to the end of each line.

Try instead of :

> k = line+ans

The following:

```
k = line.rstrip('\n') + ans
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This almost works! It does indeed add test to the end of the line, but, it writes the next line immediately after. So, I get: '2 H: 4,0 : Where to search for information : googletest3 H: 7,0 : An integer with only 2 divisors : prime' in the same line. But this is a great direction for me!

Comment: You can either add manually "\n" to the phrase,  or write something like "str(line.rstrip('\n'), ans, '\n')"